# THREE.js: Geometry/text/shapes example not working on my local machine

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to learn WebGL and want to use the library `three.js`.

[Here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text_shapes) are the examples that are using `three.js`.

The example *geometry/ text/shapes* -which opens when you use the link above, shows the text **three.js simple text.** and you can download the source code for all the examples in the bottom right corner.

I did that and opened the same example (`webgl_geometry_text_shapes.html`) on my PC and it shows the same page, but without the Text.
When I inspect the page it says

> three.js:32090 Failed to load
>   file:///C:/grubera/Web-Programmierung/three.js-master/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

U can see that in the image below, too!

[Inspect Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPfcN.png)

Does anyone know how can I fix this issue? I am completely new to `HTML`, `JavaScript`, and the whole web Programming stuff!

I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: [this article might be helpful](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-setup.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run your webpage/threejs app directly from your hard drive. Typically, you'll want to run a server (usually a local server for development) to serve your app/webpage, and assets like images, fonts, scripts, etc, order to avoid these issues.

There are a number of ways to do this - I tend to use `http-server` when serving static content for simple apps that I'm developing locally.

You can set `http-server` up for your project by following these steps:

1. [Install node and npm](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)
2. [Install http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)
3. Run `http-server` from terminal/console, from the root directory of your project

Once you've done all of this, you'll be able to access your project in the browser (from http://localhost:8080 by default). You should find this fixes the error you're seeing -

hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Your using absolute path for what looks like a font file. Instead of overcoming cross origin limitations. Try to include the file using a relative url.

Comment: "Your using absolute path for what looks like a font file" — The source code which shows the path is not included in the question. It doesn't matter anyway, the problem is the use of a `file:` scheme URL, not if it is a relative or absolute path that resolves as one.